# Selecting employees from database where the company contains between 1 and 5 employees

Tags: mysql

So far I have this query:

```
SELECT
    c.id AS company_id,
    c.company_name,
    COUNT(*) AS employee_count
FROM
    ct_companies c
INNER JOIN ct_employees e ON c.id = e.company_id
GROUP BY
    c.domain,
    c.postcode,
    c.company_name
HAVING
    (
        employee_count >= 1
        AND employee_count <= 5
    )
ORDER BY
    employee_count DESC
```

Now, this works great, it selects companies who have at least 1 employee but no more than 5 and shows me the employee count.

But what I want to be able to do, is select every employee within a company, but only where that company has between 1 and 5 employees like above.

So something like

```
SELECT e.id FROM ct_employees e WHERE (employee_count >= 1 AND employee_count <= 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT e.id, 
       d.employee_count 
FROM   ct_employees e 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT c.id     AS company_id, 
                          COUNT(*) AS employee_count 
                   FROM   ct_companies c 
                          INNER JOIN ct_employees e1 
                                  ON c.id = e1.company_id 
                   GROUP  BY c.domain, 
                             c.postcode, 
                             c.id 
                   HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1 
                          AND COUNT(*) <= 5) d 
               ON d.company_id = e.company_id 
ORDER  BY employee_count DESC
```